# How to get highest value of each item with the same id?

Tags: c#, linq

All data recieved from db.
Table contains items with the itemId and points. How can I get a list with items that has the most point (between same itemId).
_db.Table...
Ex.

```
1  itemId = a1   50 points
2     a1   10 points
3 b1 15 points
```

I want to get :

```
a1, 50 points
 b1 with 15 points.
```

How can it be done with using system.Linq?

Answer (score 1):

```
from item in items
group item by item.id into itemgrp
select new {id = itemgrp.key, maxPts = itemgrp.max(i => i.points };
```